# Default Form Fields Value Mess With Form Action

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a simple php and jquery contact form (3 fields: name - email - message), whose input field are coded like this:

```
<input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>" class="requiredField"/>
```

I'd like those field to have a default value, rather than being empty. At the same time i wouldn't trust using the placeholder attribute, since it is not universally supported.

I found this jquery script that does the job in an excellent way:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( ".contact_form_field" )
.focus(function() {
var $this = $(this);
if (!$this.data('default')) {
$this.data('default', $this.val());
}
if ($this.val() == $this.data('default')) {
$this.val('')
.css('color', '#000');
}
})
.blur(function() {
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.val() == '') {
$(this).val($this.data('default'))
.css('color', '#666');
}
})
.css('color', '#666')
});
</script>
```

However, to make it work i had to change the value attributes of the field to the desidered placeholder text:

```
<input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="Name" class="requiredField"/>
```

This, predictably, seems to interfere with the form action that should prevent the mail being sent if there are empty fields:

```
if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
}
```

I thought i just had to change the string to

```
if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === 'Name') { or

if(trim($_POST['contactName']) == 'Name') { or
```

but it doesn't seem to work. The mail gets sent even if the field is left untouched (not empty, since the "Name" text is displayed).

I am at a loss to understand what i'm doing wrong, any input (sorry for the pun x_x) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is also a jQuery plugin called `watermark` that has no effect on the actual value of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placeholders are quite ready to use today. But if you still don't trust it you can use old solution based on onfocus and onblur attributes. Here's an example:

```
<input onfocus="if(this.value==='default value') this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value==='') this.value='default value'">
```

Answer (score 0):

create an array with all the default values and test to see if the submitted value is part of the default value

```
$defaultValue = array('', 'Name');
if(in_array(trim($_POST['contactName']), $defaultValue) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great and quick feedback.. StackOverflow awesome as usual!
Though i'll disappoint you cause i went for the laziest solution and installed the Watermark plugin as suggested by @DevlshOne. :(

Thanks again!